# How to use localization inside stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use localization inside stateless widget and works fine. But when i change it to stateful widget always return null. i use arb file for localization. How to use localization in stateful widget?

this stateless

```
class statelessPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    consuming(context, theme, child) {
      return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: theme.getTheme(),
          locale: theme.getLocale(),
          supportedLocales: L10n.all,
          localizationsDelegates: [
            AppLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          home: statefulWidget(),
        );
    }

    return Consumer<ThemeNotifier>(
      builder: consuming,
    );
  }
}
```

to this stateful

```
class AnotherPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnotherPageState createState() => _AnotherPageState();
}

class _AnotherPageState extends AnothertState {
  MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: theme.getTheme(),
          locale: theme.getLocale(),
          //supportedLocales: L10n.all,
          localizationsDelegates: [
            AppLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          home: Scaffold(
          ),
       )
    }
```

Comment: There should be no difference, please share the code (MaterialApp widget and your stateful widget)

Comment: its different, stateful always show null for localization

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use:

```
    theme: theme.getTheme(),
      locale: theme.getLocale(),
      //supportedLocales: L10n.all,
      localizationsDelegates: [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
```

in the StatefulWidget. As I understand it, you only put this at the top widget of your app which is usually a StatelessWidget.

Comment: i use StatefulWidget because i use Consumer or ChangeNotifierProvider to listen locale language changed in setting